# If I use a DC motor as a generator, would the output current be AC or DC

Tags: dc-motor, generator, back-emf

I am thinking of using a DC motor as a generator for a toy, but I am unsure if I need to do a full wave rectification if the output current is AC.

Comment: (1) Should be DC. (2) I would suggest to do the following to prove concept: (a) Use two identical DC motors, eg. 12V 370 geared DC motor at 100 rpm. (b) Use a shaft coupler to link the shafts together. (c) Power the "driver" motor with 12V DC, so moving around 100 rpm. (c) The linked "generator" motor would also move at the same speed. (d) The generator motor's shaft, without gearing, would move at a much higher speed, perhaps 4,000 rpm.   / to continue, ...

Comment: (e) The generator motor output should be around 12V (or a bit less). (f) The generator's "communator ring" mechanism would do the rectifying jog, converting 12V AC rms to 12VDC.